# Alternative to protein shake after gym

Tags: nutrition, supplements

I get the feeling if I don't drink protein shake after workout I feel low. Is it a mind thing or is it really a nutritional fact that hits the body? I usually don't go to gym and it has been 1 year since I could afford any supplements so I stopped it as I think I will be putting my body under stress if I don't have protein shake.

Is it really true or just my mind being lazy? What are the alternatives when one does not have protein powder to gulp down?

Answer (score 1):

Your protein levels are usually low after a work out. same with everything else. So your body absorbs pretty much everything(almost everything) your put in it. Look up post work out meals and nutrition. Optimum Nutrition makes a protein specifically for after workout shake. It's called Hydrolized Whey. When your protein levels are low your body can go into a catabolic state so it's important to re fuel to stay anabolic.

Comment: interesting, any references for further reading?

Answer (score 0):

An Apple (or other fruit).

After a workout it is highly likely that your glucose stores are depleted. Something healthy and containing some sugar will make you feel a lot better.

Comment: But isn't apple a slow digesting food, from what i know you need something that can quickly become available in bloodstream?

Answer (score 0):

For a very simple answer:

Gummy bears, pixy stix, skim milk, egg whites.  Fast carbs and quick protein absorption.

Or...

You're splitting hairs if you're not working out because you don't have fast acting carbs and/or a protein powder to eat directly after strength training.

Eat a balanced diet based on macros for whatever your goal is (cut, bulk, maintain), push/pull the weight, and sleep.  Rinse and repeat.

Training and diet are simple, supplements are **NOT** necessary to build an amazing physique that you'll be proud of and your friends will be jealous of, don't over think it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the shakes as much as I tend to feel bloated when drinking them post workout. But there are a few [alternatives to protein shakes](http://www.viciouscandy.com/alternatives-to-protein-shakes-gym/) that I like including chocolate chip cookie dough balls.